# How to sort alphabetically using a dropdown menu in React

Tags: reactjs, typescript, switch-statement

I am in the middle of trying to get my dropdown menu to sort alphabetically when I click on one of the options. I have a function that changes the value in the state and then another function that contains a switch statement to alphabetize when the proper case is selected. I am not sure where to put my function that contains the switch statement. As of right now I have my updateSortByFilter being called in the onChange. Any tips would be great. Thank you.

```
updateSortByFilter = (event: any) => {
    this.setState({
     sortDropdown: event.target.value
    });
  };

  sortDropdown = () => {
  this.props.projects.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
  let aVal = '';
  let bVal = '';

  switch (this.state.sortDropdown) {
    case 'name':
      aVal = a.name;
      bVal = b.name;
      break;
    case 'date':
      aVal = a.date;
      bVal = b.date;
      break;
    default:
      aVal = a.name;
      bVal = b.name;
      break;
  }

  //ascending sort
  if (aVal < bVal) {
    return -1;
  } if (aVal > bVal) {
    return 1;
  } return 0;
  })
 }

  render() {
   return (

        <Form.Group>
          <Form.Label>Sort By:</Form.Label>
          <select onChange={this.updateSortByFilter}>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
          </select>
        </Form.Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with an extra param, i.e.

```js
const projects = [{
  name: "c",
  date: new Date("2020/01/02"),
}, {
  name: "b",
  date: new Date("2020/12/12"),
}, {
  name: "a",
  date: new Date("2020/06/06"),
}]

const sortIt = sortBy => (a, b) => {
  if (a[sortBy] > b[sortBy]) {
    return 1;
  } else if (a[sortBy] < b[sortBy]) {
    return -1;
  }
  return 0;
}

const sortedByDate = projects.sort(sortIt('date'));
const sortedByName = projects.sort(sortIt('name'));

console.log(sortedByDate);
console.log(sortedByName);
```

And this way you're open to bring any property in the first level object and filter by it's string value.

Or in one line

```
const sortIt = sortBy => (a, b) => a[sortBy] > b[sortBy] ? 1 : a[sortBy] < b[sortBy] ? -1 : 0;
```